# How to generate fix url with SSL/TLS with ngrok

Tags: ngrok

I am running an apache server with a virtual host, called: `test.net.ngrok.io`.
What i would like to get is to make my virtual accessible for public with a ssl or tls certificate.
I have the `pro` package, see: https://ngrok.com/pricing
So far I managed to run this command, but without ssl:

`./ngrok http -region=us -hostname=test.net.ngrok.io -host-header=rewrite test.net.ngrok.io:80`.
Is there a way to make a fixed public url with ssl|tls certificate ? If yes, can you help me with the exact command to make the ngrok tunnel ?

Thank you

Comment: Did you think about switching to a paid plan?

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov the Pro package it is a paid plan